# Jest not passing test when throw error

Tags: ecmascript-6, jestjs, nock

I'm testing my code with Jest and mocking http call with nock JSON response:
    it('should throw error when record does not exists', async() => {

```
          const noExistsJSONFile = path.join(__dirname, "../../../data/api/project/non-existing.json");
          nock(__ROOT_API__)
            .defaultReplyHeaders({ 'access-control-allow-origin': '*' })
            .get('/projects/2500')
            .replyWithFile(404, noExistsJSONFile);

          const response = await getProject('/projects/2500');

          expect(response).toThrowError(`${notExisting.errorMessage} (Code: ${notExisting.errorCode})`);

        });
      });
```

There is an async function which should fail if the status code is > 300 and create new Error:

```
export async function get(pathname) {
    const params = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    };
    let response = await fetch(`${__ROOT_API__}${pathname}`, params);
    if (!validateStatusCode(response)) {
      var error = new Error(response.statusText)
      error.response = response
      throw error
    }
    return response.json();
}
```

At moment when I'm running test JEST is throwing:

```
  11 |     let response = await fetch(`${__ROOT_API__}${pathname}`, params);
      12 |     if (!validateStatusCode(response)) {
    > 13 |       var error = new Error(response.statusText)
      14 |       error.response = response
      15 |       throw error
      16 |     }

      at _callee$ (src/services/project/project.js:13:19)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:296:22)
      at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
      at step (node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)
      at node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:28:13
```

When I looking on chrome network traffic I response which I need. What is the reason behind JEST error

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're starting the fetch, thus, throwing the error before the `toThrowError` matcher. Furthermore, this is an async call, which makes it a bit more complex to test, for this reason, instead of using the `toThrow` matcher which is used for sync functions calls, you can use a try/catch block with the `await` syntax, as explained in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous#async-await):

```js
expect.assertions(1);
try {
  await getProject('/projects/2500');
} catch (e) {
   expect(e).toMatch(`${notExisting.errorMessage} (Code: ${notExisting.errorCode})`);
}
```

`expect.assertions(1)` tells jest to expect one assertion inside the test.

Comment: Not really working as I expect that I will get 404 with {message: 'Error', code: 412} and getting only  Received:
      [Error: Not Found]

Comment: Also, I think it's more connected how nock is passing error response to which will be later passed to throw error

Comment: I can't have an accurate inspection just by here, but probably the string you have to match is the one in the Error constructor `res.errorMessage`, avoid using the equal matcher for instance, try first just to compare the error message as in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I done small changes to code - not working 100% as expected but close.
Change a little bit response function :

```
export async function get(pathname) {
    const params = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    };
    let response = await fetch(`${__ROOT_API__}${pathname}`, params);
    if (!validateStatusCode(response)) {
      const res = await response.json();
      throw new Error(res.errorMessage);
    }
    return response.json();
}
```

And test looks like this:

```
 it('should throw error when record does not exists', async () => {
      const noExistsJSONFile = path.join(__dirname, "../../../data/api/project/non-existing.json");
      nock(__ROOT_API__)
        .defaultReplyHeaders({ 'access-control-allow-origin': '*' })
        .get('/projects/2500')
        .replyWithFile(404, noExistsJSONFile);

      try {
        await getProject('/projects/2500');
      } catch (error) {
        expect(error).toEqual(new Error('error message'));

      }

    });
```